# How to detect and avoid circular dependencies in computed properties in Vue

Tags: vue.js, design-patterns

Here is a simple example for a vue3 component that has got a circular dependency in computed properties:

```
<template>
  <p>{{ c1 }} {{ c2 }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Test",
  computed: {
    c1() {
      return this.c2;
      // general case: function(this.c2, .... other data...)
    },
    c2() {
      return this.c1;
      // general case: function(this.c1, .... other data...)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This results in an endless loop and the component is dysfunctional, the template is not being rendered. The point is that this problem can easily occur via longer loops involving several components communicating via emits and props, each having some computed properties. Maybe also some data in a `vuex` store is involved in the loop.

In other words, it can be very hard to spot such a problem in a complex application when some of your components don't work as expected (recently I had this problem, that's why I am posting the question). Many applications need to share data and state information between the components.

Are there any ideas on how to detect such problems systematically, e.g. using some tool, or, using specific component design patterns to avoid the problem as far as possible?

Comment: Jus change the name of the computed handler like `c1` to `computeC1` and `c2` to `computeC2`! That would fix your problem

Comment: do you have a real issue and code you're trying to fix? I've never had this issue before as the logic of what's being built prevents it

Comment: And why do you think 'the logic what's being built preserves it'? What is the design principle you are following? That's my question.